# get the last value of an object Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object which I'm trying to get the last value of every key and put it into another object.

```
var setA = {
    'a':'001, 007, 101',
    'b':'052, 004, 006, 005',
    'c':'003, 002, 001'
}
```

What I'm trying to do is get the last ones like this:

```
var setB = {
    'a':'101',
    'b':'005',
    'c':'001'
}
```

How might I accomplish this?

Comment: This is a nit, but each of the properties in "setA" has only one value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just:

```
var setB = {
    'a':setA.a.split(',').pop().trim(),
    'b':setA.b.split(',').pop().trim(),
    'c':setA.c.split(',').pop().trim()
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7KetR/).

Effectively this takes the value returned from the variable in `setA.a` (and so on...), splits that string, at the `,` characters, into an array, pops off the last value of that array and trims the whitespace from it.

The following was raised from [jbabey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11479762/82548)'s answer, when I remembered that a string could be treated as an array of characters:

```
var setA = {
    'a': '001, 007, 101',
    'b': '052, 004, 006, 005',
    'c': '003, 002, 001'
},
    setB = {
    'a': setA.a.slice(-3),
    'b': setA.b.slice(-3),
    'c': setA.c.slice(-3)
}

console.log(setB);​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7KetR/).

References:

- [`pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop).
- [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).
- [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).
- [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim).

Answer (score 4):

A loop?

```
var setB = {}
for (var o in setA) {
  var s = setA[o].split(', '),
      x = s[s.length - 1]
  setB[o] = x
}
```

Comment: missing semicolons, implicit globals, and bad variable names... i would not want to maintain this code, but we get the gist :P

Comment: global yah typo. everything else, meh, as example seems fine

Comment: Also, *missing semicolons*? not relevant now a days anymore, go tell that to the [NPM](https://github.com/isaacs/npm) guys, xD

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex for that

```
var setB = {
    'a':setA.a.match(/(\d+)$/)[1],
    'b':setA.b.match(/(\d+)$/)[1],
    'c':setA.c.match(/(\d+)$/)[1]
}
```

`/(\d+)$/` will match the last digits in the string

Answer (score 2):

If you know that you always want the last 3 characters of the string, you can just use [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

```
var setA = {
    'a':'001, 007, 101',
    'b':'052, 004, 006, 005',
    'c':'003, 002, 001'
}

var setB = {};

for (var item in setA) {
    setB[item] = setA[item].substring(setA[item].length-3);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/X6J2p/

Answer (score 1):

This code does the trick:

```
var setB={},temp,prop;
for(prop in setA){
    temp=setA[prop].split(', ');
    temp=temp[temp.length-1];
    setB[prop]=temp;
}
```